# Getting a right parenthesis error in SQL

Tags: sql, view, report, error-code

I am getting an error that says I am missing right parenthesis, but I'm not. I dont understand what is going wrong with my query.

```
CREATE VIEW HB_INV(Book Title, Publisher Name, Price, Units On Hand) AS
SELECT BOOK.TITLE, PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_CODE||'-'||PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_NAME,
BOOK.PRICE, INVENTORY.ON_HAND
FROM BOOK, PUBLISHER, INVENTORY
WHERE BOOK.PUBLISHER_CODE = PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_CODE
AND BOOK.BOOK_CODE = INVENTORY.BOOK_CODE;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Units on Hand.  Make it all one word.

**Edit starts here**

Actually, it's also "Book Title" and "Publisher Name".  Make all the fields in your view single words.

Comment: I did what Sico below said with all the words and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL Server you need Square Brackets around [Units On Hand] and also, if that is a concatenation for publisher code, use '+' instead of '||'